# Snapseed vs Lightroom Mobile for editing RAW images

Tags: image-editing, raw-format

I have a wifi card in my DSLR camera that is able to transfer RAW images to my mobile directly.

I'm planning to edit pictures on my mobile if possible.

Wanted to know which app is better for the same. Lightroom mobile or Snapseed.

I started using Snapseed, it seems to be doing what I need comfortably.

My questions are:
 1. If I should try Lightroom mobile as well? Is it worth the time that I would spend learning the tricks for Lightroom.
 2. Are there any major differences between the two apps
 3. Do I've to pay for Lightroom mobile?
 4. Lastly do you think the workflow is bad? DSLR->Mobile->Share(?)

Answer (score 1):

I use Snapseed, mainly because to edit .RAW on Lightroom Mobile you have to pay, VSCO can also edit .RAW files, you can't do much as on Snapseed but you have better filters to play with. It depends on what you are trying to edit.